# Vibrate with Apache Cordova when function is executed (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery, api, chat, cordova, vibration

I am wrote a simple chat room. The code is below. I would like to use apache cordova to make the device vibrate when the user receives a message. How can I implemnt this?

http://pastie.org/5085307

The code is at that link. I have included both the vibrate code and chat room code.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to put the call to navigator.notification.vibrate(2000) at line 83 of your app.  You also need to include the script tag for cordova in the head or it just won't work. There is no need to wrap navigator.notification.vibrate(2000) in a vibrate function inside of onDeviceReady.